# Dynamically create a class by interface

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, code-generation, expression-trees

I have some expirience with `.Net Expressions`, when I'm able to dynamically generate methods. It's fine, it's good.

But now I need to generate a whole class, and it seems that the only way to do it is Emit whole IL which is totally inacceptable (it's impossible to support).

Assume we have following interface:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    [Description("5")]
    int Bar();
    [Description("true")]
    bool Baz();
}
```

which should be converted to:

```
public class Foo : IFoo
{
    public int Bar() => 5;
    public bool Baz() => true;
}
```

How can I achieve it? Is it even possible without 3rd party tools and libs? I know there is plenty of useful utils on GitHub, but I really don't want to import a whole MVVM framework to just make some code generation.

If I could just use `Expressions`, and create a class with methods I already generated with it. But for now I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Would you like to generate the class at compile time or runtime?

Comment: Use .NET _[CodeDOM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2k85ax6(v=vs.110).aspx)_.  Waaay easier than mucking about in Reflection Emit :)

Comment: @SamAxe in runtime, of course. I'm able to use T4 to generate class in compile-time :)

Comment: @MickyD I worked with it, but it seems to be an overkill for this task. Yes, it's simpler than EMIT but it's a dynamic asselbmy creation, compiler generation... It's a bit complex for such easy task (I already have array of methods, I just want to compose them into one single class). And in such case i'd like to use `CSharpCodeProvider` instead :) But it's heavy.

Comment: Ahh I understand now.  Kewl, good-luck then :)

Comment: It might help if you added some of your reasoning. What is the core problem you are trying to solve, and why do you think that runtime class generation is a good way to solve the problem? It may be that it's the best solution, but it might also be that you're overcomplicating things :) And why do you think that you need to emit IL manually to create a class in runtime? You just need `TypeBuilder` to create the members, and then you can use `LambdaExpression.CompileToMethod` to get the IL code.

Comment: @Luaan that sounds interesting. Please, continue. Resoning is simple: I have a REST WCF service, and I want to generate a client for it. I can't use standard WCF proxy, and I'd liked to have it always-up-to-date, this is why I need runtime generation. That's simple.

Comment: @AlexZhukovskiy have you looked at Roslyn?

Comment: @TheBeardedLlama it's a compile-time service. I don't think it may help here. Of course, if we recompile a whole solution every time we change some proxy classes it may be done, but when we partially change assemblies on newer ones, everything may break.

Comment: @AlexZhukovskiy I have seen people using Roslyn to do similar things, but it was only a vague suggestion; you have a proper answer now, so I won't waste any more of your time

Comment: @TheBeardedLlama In the end your answer appeared the best one, see my answer below. After several years I found what fits my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm actually currently using `CodeGeneration.Roslyn` package that allows you to integrate into MSBuild pipeline and build stuff. For example, see my [REST swagger](https://github.com/Pzixel/RemoteClient.Roslyn) or [solidity -> C# codegen](https://github.com/Pzixel/Solidity.Roslyn).

Answer (score 5):

First, since you're dealing with remoting, I have to mention that this is something that .NET was originally designed from the ground up to support (back from .NET's roots as COM 2.0). Your most straightforward solution would be to implement a transparent remoting proxy - just make your own (probably generic) class deriving from `System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy`, and you can provide all the logic necessary for implement whatever function you need by overriding the `Invoke` method. Using `GetTransparentProxy`, you get the proxy implementing your interface and you're good to go.

Obviously, this has a cost at runtime, during every invocation. However, it's usually entirely unimportant next to the fact that you're making any I/O at all, especially if you're dealing with the network. In fact, unless you're in a tight loop, it's quite unimportant even when not doing I/O - only performance testing can really tell if you you're fine with the cost or not.

If you really want to pregenerate all the method bodies, rather than keeping the logic dynamic at runtime, you can exploit the fact that `LambdaExpression` gives you `CompileToMethod`. Unlike `Compile`, you don't get a nice little delegate you can call directly, but it gives you the option to use lambda expressions for building method bodies explicitly - which in turn allows you to make entire classes without resorting to delegate invocations.

A full (but simple) example:

```
void Main()
{
  var ab = AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicAssembly(new AssemblyName("TestAssembly"), AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
  var mb = ab.DefineDynamicModule("Test");

  var tb = mb.DefineType("Foo");
  tb.AddInterfaceImplementation(typeof(IFoo));

  foreach (var imethod in typeof(IFoo).GetMethods())
  {
    var valueString = ((DescriptionAttribute)imethod.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(DescriptionAttribute))).Description;

    var method = 
      tb.DefineMethod
      (
        "@@" + imethod.Name, 
        MethodAttributes.Private | MethodAttributes.Static, 
        imethod.ReturnType,
        new [] { tb }
      );

    // Needless to say, I'm making a lot of assumptions here :)
    var thisParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IFoo), "this");

    var bodyExpression =
      Expression.Lambda
      (
        Expression.Constant
        (
          Convert.ChangeType(valueString, imethod.ReturnType)
        ),
        thisParameter
      );

    bodyExpression.CompileToMethod(method);

    var stub =
      tb.DefineMethod(imethod.Name, MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.Virtual, imethod.ReturnType, new Type[0]);

    var il = stub.GetILGenerator();
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
    il.EmitCall(OpCodes.Call, method, null);
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

    tb.DefineMethodOverride(stub, imethod);
  }

  var fooType = tb.CreateType();
  var ifoo = (IFoo)Activator.CreateInstance(fooType);

  Console.WriteLine(ifoo.Bar()); // 5
  Console.WriteLine(ifoo.Baz()); // True
}

public interface IFoo
{
    [Description("5")]
    int Bar();
    [Description("true")]
    bool Baz();
}
```

If you've ever worked with .NET emits, this should be pretty straightforward. We define a dynamic assembly, module, type (ideally, you'd want to define all your types at once, in a single dynamic assembly). The tricky part is that `Lambda.CompileToMethod` only supports static methods, so we need to cheat a bit. First, we create a static method that takes `this` as an argument and compile the lamdba expression there. Then, we create a method stub - a simple piece of IL that ensures our static method is called properly. Finally, we bind the interface method to the stub.

In my example, I assume a parameter-less method, but as long as you make sure that the `LambdaExpression` uses exactly the same types as the interface method, the stub is as simple as doing all the `Ldarg`s in a sequence, a single `Call` and a single `Ret`. And if your real code (in the static method) is short enough, it will often be inlined. And since `this` is an argument like any other, if you're feeling adventurous, you could just take the method body of the generated method and put it directly into the virtual method - do note that you'd need to do that in two passes, though.

Comment: Amazing work, thank you. But is it possible to remove this ldarg-red proxy at all? I'm working on it, but I'd like to know your opinion. It's because of `CompileToMethod` for statics only?

Comment: @AlexZhukovskiy You can take the IL code from the generated method directly, and put it in another method. However, it means you need to create the types and static methods first to get to the IL / method body, and then create a different type (a derived type, if you need to preserve `this`) to put the IL into. And I'm not 100% sure how safe that would be anyway. You could also use `LambdaCompiler` directly, though that's probably a bad idea. Why are you trying to avoid it? You only need one helper method to create any kind of stub you need, and keep it well documented (and test-covered).

Comment: You're right again. I'm working on this method right now. I'l post a link to gist or something when I finish.

Comment: [Here](https://gist.github.com/Pzixel/5865643d161b6892aba58c76551e55b3) is my realisation, as I promised. I use code-generation to generate a client for WCF REST service. In realisation we can call HttpClient with parameters and that's all. Seems to be very simple in use. It's a concept, but it's fine imo.

Comment: @AlexZhukovskiy I see one bug - in your `Ldarg_S` case, you pass `i` as an integer argument. ILGenerator isn't smart, it just literally translates what you say 1:1, so it doesn't fix the argument - `Ldarg_S` takes a `byte`, so you must explicitly do `il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_S, (byte)i);`. Otherwise you write three bytes more than you're supposed to, and it's going to produce an invalid program.

Comment: I know about it, but it seems unlikely that there is some method with more than 255 arguments. This is why I didn't use cast there. Buy you are right, I add some check at start. But it's anyway just a concept, it's plenty of things should be enhanced there.

Comment: @AlexZhukovskiy No, you don't understand. Since the argument to `Emit` is an `int`, not a `byte`, `Emit` will emit four bytes instead of one, and break the whole method. You *must* use the `byte` overload, or it isn't going to work, full stop. It's not about checking that `i` is not bigger than 255, it's about the overload of `Emit` that's called.

Comment: Hmm, ok. It's strange then becuase it's working right now.

Comment: @AlexZhukovskiy Well, there's the fortunate/unfortunate choice of opcodes in IL. Think about how your instruction is laid out - `0x0E04` for the `ldarg_s 4` then `0x00` three times for three NOPs in a sequence. The thing that saves you is that LSB is the first byte, and the rest comes as NOPs. So you're right that in your case, it doesn't produce an invalid program - through sheer luck. But fix the problem anyway, just to remind yourself that the method overload you pick for `Emit` matters - in your case, instead of emitting a single opcode, you actually emitted four, unwittingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CodeDOM and Emit. However, I don't think that it is worth it.

For a similar thing I am using the following library:
http://www.castleproject.org/projects/dynamicproxy/

It is able to create proxy classes even when the target class is not available (you have to intercept all methods then).

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a dynamic backer you can use DynamicClassFactory

```
void Main()
{
    var properties = typeof(IFoo).GetProperties()
                        .Select(x => new DynamicProperty(x.Name, x.PropertyType))
                        .ToList();

    Type type = DynamicClassFactory.CreateType(properties);

    dynamic dynamicFooClass = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    dynamicFooClass.Key = 1;
    dynamicFooClass.Description = "Freddy";

    Console.WriteLine(dynamicFooClass);
}

public interface IFoo
{
    int Key { get; set; }
    string Description { get; set; }
}
```